# change product category ABC to HELLO (woocommerce question)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron, inventory

1. We create an product in woocommerce.
2. Then we assign categories: cat1, cat2, cat3 to product.

After some days i wanna start a script to change category cat2 to cat4 in all products. How do to that via php script like this:
run domain.de/start.php will change all products with category cat2 to cat4.

Answer (score 1):

'cat-1' is old category and 'cat-2' is new.
Tested and working

```
if( isset( $_GET['update_cats'] ) && $_GET['update_cats'] =='yes' ){
   add_action("init","change_products_cats");
}
function change_products_cats(){
    $args = array(
    'category' => array( 'cat-1' ),
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        wp_set_object_terms(  $value->id, 'cat-2', 'product_cat' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! 1. I can add this into start.php file and run it via browser?

Comment: code in functions.php

Comment: I need to run it via browser (open url to start a script). The functions.php will not work for me.

Comment: if you are working in wordpress then functions.php will run automatically.

Comment: but i need to change the category per click, not automatic. :-) So we need an option to trigger this script by starting the URL domain.de/start.php

Comment: I have updated answer now you can work like
https://your-site/?update_cats=yes

Comment: I test it and its working fine. But one small issue we have now.
Before: cat1, cat2, cat3. After running your script the product have only one cat: cat4. But we need result like this: cat1, cat4, cat3. So we do not wanna remove all other categories, just wanna replace cat2 with cat4.

Comment: wp_set_object_terms(  $value->id, 'cat-2', 'product_cat' ); can get array like this
wp_set_object_terms(  $value->id, array('cat-2','cat-3','cat-4'), 'product_cat' );